# Understand format of the parameters in binary file

Tags: files, binary

I have a binary file which in it there are some parameters stored as binary, for example :
x , y , z , u ,p1 , p2 ,..    up to 12 parameters.

I used "Ghex" to show it, Ghex shows some hexadecimal values but I cannot understand the format of the file(how these parameters have been saved).

Is there any way(program , ...) to understand how these parameters have been saved?

Comment: Question closed as off-topic, however it perfectly belongs on Ask Ubuntu. Questions about binary files and their behavior on Ubuntu are perfectly alright. In addition, the question asks about a particular tool which may be used on Ubuntu. There's plenty of similar questions on this site, so I don't see how this one is off-topic.

Comment: I disagree. The question is not about tools, but a specific binary file, without any information as to origin of the file. In short it can be literally **anything**.

Answer (score 1):

Read `man od`. `od` will let you specify any format you like. For instance, if your file is 4byte integers, you'd use `od --format=dI`.

It depends on what **type** of variables the "up to 12 parameters" are, and how much space (how many bytes) they take up in the file, and the "endian-ness" of the data (is a 4 byte integer stored as 4321 or 1234 in the file?).

If the file is too complex for `od`, you could look at Perl's `unpack` function, with `perldoc -f unpack`, or the Python `struct` module.

The real way to understand the format is to look at the program that created the file, or the documentation, or ...., track down the programmer and inquire.

Thanks to @steeldriver

Comment: +1 the Python `struct` module also provides a binary unpacker - it might also be worth mentioning endian-ness.